# How to access data out of a join table in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many association between a user and a task.

I wanted a user to join a task and created an action in the user controller as follows:

```
  def joinTask
    @user = current_user
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @users_tasks =  @task
    @task.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        format.html { redirect_to [@task.column.board.project, @task.column.board], notice: 'You joined the task successfully' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

To see if that is properly working I wanted to list all users that belong to a specific task. For that I added an action to the user controller where I am trying to get all users that belong to a task:

```
def showTeam
    @users = Task.find(params[:id]).users

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # showTeam.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users}
    end
end
```

But I always get the error

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

when it tries to render the html page to get the users names...

Am I on the wrong track?

Models:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :weight, :story_id, :column_id, :board_id

  belongs_to :story, :foreign_key => "story_id"
  belongs_to :column, :foreign_key => "column_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :name, :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :status
 has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
 has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
end
```

I call the actions:

```
<%= link_to 'Join task', joinTask_path(task), :class => 'btn' %>
<%= link_to 'Show Team', showTeam_path(task), :class => 'btn' %>
```

The rootes are defined as follows:

```
match "joinTask_user/:id" => "users#joinTask", :as => :joinTask
match "showTeam_task/:id" => "tasks#showTeam", :as => :showTeam
```

And in the end the showTeam.html.erb is rendered and there I want to access the users name:

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you also post your `User` and `Task` model files as well, please.

Comment: Also add the relevant portions of your view please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're never creating a relation between your users and tasks.

```
@user = current_user
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
@users_tasks =  @task
@task.save
```

I think what you meant is

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
@task.users << current_user
@task.save
```

You shouldn't have to use the `update_attributes`. ]

Also, in your show view, you're loading `@users`, but you're calling `@user.name`.

If you want to show all the user names, it should be more along the lines of

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <p>
    <b>Name:</b>
    <%= user.name %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

You can verify if you have a relation in `rails console` by finding your task and calling `task.users` on it.

In any case, if you're just starting this project, I suggest reading on [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for your tasks as this is the typical use case for them.